# how to read multipart/form-data post stream in WCF Service without dependencies

Tags: c#, wcf, http-post

I have a C# client authorized to send multipart form post to my WCF service running on the server. I am able to receive the post stream in the WCF, but I can't find any way to access specific parts in the post stream , for example, the following post:

```
------------5726e76222c84e648591b75930afea5d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

1.txt
------------5726e76222c84e648591b75930afea5d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileformat"

txt
------------5726e76222c84e648591b75930afea5d
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.txt"
Content-Type: application/msword

This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.
------------5726e76222c84e648591b75930afea5d--
```

this post indicates a text file sent from the client, I need only to know the file name and format before storing the entire post as byte array in my backend.

is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I figured out how to solve this

You need to use Multipart data form for posting and then parsing the form from WCF server side.